# NoClassFoundError: java.util.stream.Stream

Tags: android, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror

I am writing an Android app using Kotlin.

I am receiving NoClassFoundError for java.util.stream.Stream.

At no point in my app am I using that class.

It happens when I open an ad and appears to be part of the serialization process.
It does not happen on all my devices. Only on my older one (5.1.1).
It also does not happen on all the activities.

I'm guessing that it is to do with what it is trying to Serialize. However, I am not sure where to even start.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.stream.Stream
    at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
    at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:479)
    at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getDexCacheType(ArtMethod.java:191)
    at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getReturnType(ArtMethod.java:145)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(Method.java:184)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:771)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:566)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:279)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1554)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1389)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2919)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3296)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.stream.Stream" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/il.co.anykey.games.cardflip-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:53)
    at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:479) 
    at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getDexCacheType(ArtMethod.java:191) 
    at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getReturnType(ArtMethod.java:145) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType(Method.java:184) 
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:771) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:566) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:279) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:1055) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:268) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1554) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497) 
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1389) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669) 
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2919) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3296) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.stream.Stream
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 45 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: I'm getting in the exact same situation on an Android 5.1 device. It happens when i start an activity to choose a file from the file system, or even press the device's home button, and my app's activity state is being saved ....did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features) says `java.util.stream` require API level 24 or higher. Android 5.1.1 is API 22, it doesn't have `java.util.stream.Stream` class.

Comment: The thing is I am not using Stream. The problem was caused by the fact that I was extending a class that has a method that uses Stream (even though I was not making any use of it). Seems that serializing it causes problems.